# Blender keeps flashing not responding

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am using windows 10 and the latest version of blender and even tried to reset windows however blender keeps flashing not responding and the complete UI flashes.
Please help

Comment: Tech support is outside the scope of this forum. You'll get better answers from BlenderArtists.org That being said, I'll try to help out.

Comment: If you can add which package version are you using (.msi - installer or zip version)? If using the .msi, try the zip version (ie: simply unpack thew zip and run blender.exe) since "blender is installation free" (copyright Ton Rosendaal https://youtu.be/spKJ2jbnVI8?t=929)

Comment: Most of those errors have to do with the drivers for the graphics card. Update to the latest version at the manufacturer's website.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that could cause this problem. It could be an old video driver. It could be a corrupt download.

The first thing I'd try is browse to C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming and delete the folder called "Blender Foundation." This is where Blender keeps all kinds of caches, settings, configurations, etc. Deleting this folder is like resetting Blender to the factory default configuration.

If that doesn't help, post your problem on BlenderArtists.org with a bit more detail about what "flashing" means, what GPU you have, when you last updated your drivers, and whether you're on a laptop or desktop.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There should be a problem with your video driver.
Do install the driver using disk you've got when buying it or go to the website of your graphic-card and download the latest driver available.